# Run latest Firefox or Chrome on Windows XPembedded

Tags: windows-xp-embedded

Is it possible to run the latest versions of Firefox (13.0.0.1) or Chrome (20.0) on Windows XP Embedded?

Answer (score 2):

XPe is simply componentized XP, so as long as the browser you want will run on XP (Chrome says it supports XP, I imagine FireFox does too though I didn't check that), then it's possible to make it run on XPe.

That doesn't necessarily mean it will run on your OS, though.  Since XPe is componentized, you have to ensure that all of the OS components that Chrome/FireFox/Etc use are in the OS you build.  If the components are all there and the OS is set up to allow the browser to run (remember, it's an embedded OS and the OS designer can determine what can and cannot execute) then you're good to go.